# How quickly is the area changing with respect to the radius when the radius is 120 cm?

Tags: calculus, circles

*Concentric circles form when a stone is dropped into a pool of water*

*a) What is the average rate of change in the area of one circle with respect* *to the radius as the radius grows from 0 cm to 100 cm? (Answer: $100\pi \frac{cm^2}{cm}$)*

*b) How fast is the area changing with respect to the radius when the radius is* *120 cm?*

My attempt:

$A$ is area, $r$ is radius.

$$\frac{\Delta A}{\Delta r}=\frac{\pi(120)^2-\pi(100)^2}{120-100}$$
$$=\frac{14400\pi-10000\pi}{20}$$
$$=\frac{14400\pi}{20}-\frac{10000\pi}{20}$$
$$=720\pi-500\pi$$
$$=220\pi$$

The problem is that my text says the answer is $240\pi$, so I've gone wrong somewhere. Any help?

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry. I forgot to add $\pi$ into the text. Fixed.

Comment: I should have guessed that's what happened. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you calculated is the *average* rate of change of area between radii of 100 and 120 cm, not the *instantaneous* rate at 120 cm.

To solve this problem, note that $\frac d{dr}\pi r^2$ (derivative of the circle's area with respect to its radius) is $2\pi r$, and substituting $r=120$ yields the correct answer of $240\pi$.

Comment: Technically you get this: Let $t_0$ be a time value such that $r(t_0) = 120$. Then;

$$A(t) = \pi  \cdot (r(t))^2 \Rightarrow A'(t) \Bigr|_{t = t_0} =  \pi \cdot \frac{d}{dt}( r(t) \cdot r(t)) \Bigr|_{t_0} = 2 \pi \cdot r(t) \cdot r'(t) \Bigr|_{t_0} = 2\pi\cdot 120 \cdot r'(t_0)$$ why we can assume $r'(t_0) = 1$?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood In the physical interpretation given in the question, $r=kt$ with k constant. We can choose an arbitrary unit for time such that $r=t$ (and hence $r'=1$).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel why is it that we can say $r(t) = kt$ ? Why does the radius have to be subjected to growing linearly?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I could have picked another function for $r(t)$, but the first part of the question states that the average area rate change from 0 to 100 is $100\pi$. A linear function is the simplest function that can satisfy this first part. Then again, if the radius was growing non-linearly it would have been stated in the question, but it is not.

Comment: Taxei I am not trying to disagree with you at all. I was just really trying to see if the actual question is incomplete. There should a mention of how the radius grows for this problem to make sense.